# Should we accept title edits to reflect when a question was asked?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I've noticed a few questions relating to current events being edited to have the date they were asked in the title - [this one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/47765/can-the-uk-and-the-eu-delay-brexit-again-as-of-2019-11-17) just came up in the review queue and I accepted it without really thinking, but it did then strike me that this doesn't really add any information - the date the question was asked is already recorded.

Is this something we want to encourage, or should we avoid these types of edits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, no. I don't think this helps others find the question, nor is it very useful when you stumble upon the question. In some exceptional cases a date may be helpful, for example when it's a much publicized deadline (e.g. the *29th of March 2019*, at one point Brexit deadline or *December 2019 election* to refer to the upcoming UK election). If we do include those, it's probably best to write the month in words to avoid confusion (see this [question on Skeptics Meta](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4415/44381)).

#### Bonus: how to search by date

Quoting from [the help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

> **Dates**
>
> You can use specific dates or date ranges to narrow results down to posts created or active within a certain time period, using the following operators:
>
> - `created:` to specify when the posts were created
> - `lastactive:` for posts active in a specified time period
>
> Dates can be entered in the following formats:
>
> - Absolute dates:
>
>   - year only – e.g., `created:2012..2013` searches posts created from January 1, 2012 through December 31, 2013; `created:2012` searches posts created from January 1, 2012 through December 31, 2012.
>   - year and month – e.g., created:2012-04..2012-05 searches posts created between April 1, 2012 and May 31, 2012.
>   - day, month, and year – e.g., `lastactive:2012-04-03` searches posts who were last active between 12:00 AM on April 3, 2012 and 11:59 PM on April 3, 2012.
> - Relative dates:
>
>   - `1y`, `1m`, and `1d` are shorthand for "last year", "last month", and "yesterday" - e.g., if today is April 15, `created:1m` searches posts created between March 1 and March 31. (You can substitute any number for `1` to look back that many years, months, or days.)
>   - Relative dates in a range (`1y..`) look back to the same date in the previous period - e.g., if you want to see all the posts active in the last three months, use `lastactive:3m..` On April 15, that will show posts from January 15 up to the most recently active. You can close the range as well: `lastactive:3m..1m`.
>
> **Please note** that all times are recorded in UTC; the results may not match your timezone.

Answer (score 2):

I made that edit because I kept seeing multiple identical-seeming questions pop-up in the "related questions" section on the right. (well, not that specific one, but the habit of editing some time/date info into titles)

I thought it was the best course of action for questions which get asked and answered without being merged/closed multiple times, but with subtle differences. e.g. many brexit questions, and US election questions that don't specify any kind of timeframe.

Basically, I got annoyed at having to click on questions in the related bar just to find out what they were about, and started making edits. I may have gotten carried away.